# How to read UDP packet with variable length in C

Tags: c, serialization, udp

I'm sending a C struct over UDP

```
struct packet{
    int numInt;
    int* intList; //malloc'ed as (sizeof(int)*numInt)
}
```

It will be serialized as `[numInt][intList[0]]...[intList[numInt-1]]`.

My understanding is that calling `recvfrom` on UDP will read the entire packet, even if the buffer doesn't hold that many bytes. Is using a really large buffer the only option I have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pass `MSG_PEEK` to `recvfrom` to find out exactly how big the buffer needs to be. So just `recvfrom` a few bytes with `MSG_PEEK` to find `numInt` and then `recvfrom` the real thing (this time without `MSG_PEEK`).

[The standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recvfrom.html) says something about `MSG_PEEK`, but [kernel.org](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/recv.2.html) spells it better:

> `MSG_PEEK`
>
> This flag causes the receive operation to return data from the
> beginning of the receive queue without removing that data from the
> queue. Thus, a subsequent receive call will return the same data.

Obviously at some point you will start wondering if doubling the number of system calls to save memory is worth it. I think it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

UDP packets are sent and received as a whole. *if* you receive it, the size is right. The only thing you have to do is to supply a big enough buffer on read() or recv() or recfrom(). The length field inside the payload is redundant, since the read() will tell you the correct size. It is also dangerous, since it relies on the sender and reciever having the same byte order.

Comment: If the sender and receiver don't understand their byte ordering then what's the point?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a small buffer, just large enough to get `numInt`, with the `MSG_PEEK` flag set.  Then you can find out the size you actually need, and receive again without `MSG_PEEK` to get the whole thing.

Answer (score -3):

I'm pretty sure recvfrom will read up to as many bytes as is told to it by its 3rd argument, len. If there are fewer bytes available, it will return what is there. If there are more, it will return up to len bytes.  You may have to make additional calls to obtain all the data your are expecting.

Comment: Won't downvote but the standard says: "*If a message is too long to fit in the supplied buffer, and MSG_PEEK is not set in the flags argument, **the excess bytes shall be discarded**.*". `SOCK_DGRAM` is unlike `SOCK_STREAM` in this regard.